# Initialization of variables matrix in a structure C

Tags: c, struct

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct { int mat[x][x]; int res; } graphe;
graphe g;
```

the problem that I can't access to the graph matrix

for example when I set :

```
int m[5][5]={{0,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0},{1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1},{0,0,1,1,0}};
graphe g = { m[5][5], 5};

for(i=0;i<lignes;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<lignes;j++)
        {
            printf("%i ",g.mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
printf("Res = %i ",g.res);
```

I have

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
Res =0
```

Normally should be:

```
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
Res =5
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `graphe g = { m[5][5], 5};` the `m[5][5]` here is simply an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ allow copying a whole array directly. Additionally, the initialization via `= {..}` allows omitting braces to initialize array/struct members. As it is currently written, you only initialize the first two elements of the `mat` member with `= { m[5][5], 5 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { int mat[5][5]; int res; } graphe;

int main(void) {
int m[5][5]={{0,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0},{1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1},{0,0,1,1,0}};
graphe g;
memcpy( g.mat, m, sizeof(m));
g.res= 5;
for(i=0;i<lignes;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<lignes;j++)
        {
            printf("%i ",g.mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
printf("Res = %i ",g.res);
```

be careful when using array 2D is not a simple affectation like simple variable (like g.res), because you have to indicate the size of your array, so you have to use memcpy for that.

Comment: thanks its working but the result its not true I don't know why ? {0,1,1,1,0},{0,1,0,1,1},{1,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,0,1}

Comment: @Anis_Stack may I ask you what additional information have you provided besides just copying-paste my example posted 1 hour before yours?

Comment: @0d0a I use the code to explain to Sami Li when use memcpy and when use simple affectation !!

Answer (score 0):

graphe.mat  is 25 (probably, it has to be at least 25 in this case) bytes of reserved memory inside the struct. But `m` is a pointer to another memory location. Neither C nor C++ allow to assign `m` to the struct's member.

If you have to copy data into the struct you have to use `memcpy` and friends. In case of copying the strings you need to handle the `'\0'` terminator too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { int mat[5][5]; int res; } graphe;

int main(void) {
int m[5][5]={{0,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0},{1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1},{0,0,1,1,0}};
graphe g;
memcpy( g.mat, m, sizeof(m));
```

[example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8550ca8e8b065144)

Comment: Its working but the result its not true : {0,1,1,1,0},{0,1,0,1,1},{1,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,0,1} I don't know why ?

Comment: @SamiLi just copy-paste the example if you cannot find the bug or please paste complete code that you execute